# Url Re-Writing with YII

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to use the YII for URL Re-Writing.
Is there any way to show the page extensions like .html or .php?
Please help I am new in YII.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`urlSuffix`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlRule#urlSuffix-detail) parameter

```
array(
    ......
    'components'=>array(
        ......
        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                'pattern1'=>'route1',
                'pattern2'=>'route2',
                'pattern3'=>'route3',
            ),
            'urlSuffix' => '.html'
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Should I put it into main.php

Comment: @JamesMartin unless config file is named differently